# Visual Studio 2017 - Publish Individual File Missing from Menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

Currently working on an MVC project, I used to be able to right click individual files such as js files, and choose publish, so I wouldn't have to publish the entire project for changes in a single file.  After installing updates the other day, I no longer have that option from the solution explorer menu when I right click a file.

Has this option moved locations?  Is there a setting I need to configure first?  Thanks!

Comment: Is your publishing profile still in place?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds crazy, but install microsoft azure  tool  in  visual studio 2017 tool list .   I am not able to  sure why  microsoft did so 
[image]